# How to consolidate queries from multiple Power BI pbix files into one file?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have two Power BI files with many sources each. Is there a convenient way to move all the queries and keep all the transformations done in M? In other words, I would like to have all of the queries from both files in one location.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "see marge all the sources". Do you want the set of all queries from both files?

Comment: @AlexisOlson yes, preferably all of them at once - one below the other

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now copy and paste queries from one Power BI file to another.

Go into the query editor and select all of the queries you want to move to another file, right-click > Copy, then Paste into the same section of the destination file.

[image: Copy and Paste]

Comment: Great! Thank you! Even simpler then I thought.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin You're welcome. I've edited your question to make it more useful to future viewers. Hopefully, the downvotes will go away.